# Get response from call using Page.ClientScript

Tags: c#, asp.net

Depending on some values in my application I need to show the confirm box with an OK and a Cancel, if they click OK, it should continue and navigate to another page, otherwise if they click cancel, it should stay in the same page.

The problem I am having is that the pop up does not show UNLESS i add the return statement as follows

```
  if (true)
        {
         Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), 
        "ConfirmBox", "confirm('The numbers selected are not in the directory,"
        + sb.ToString()+
        " you wish to continue?');", true);
                        return;
         }
    Response.Redirect("~/homepage.aspx");
```

As you can see this would not work because it would never get to the redirection because of the return, but without the return even if the condition is true it skips the pop up. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried your codes, and the action is the same with you.
There is my solution provide with you:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Redirect()
{
location.href = "~/homepage.aspx";
}
</script>
<script runat="server">
void yourFunc()
{
if (true)
        {
         Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), 
        "ConfirmBox", "if(confirm('The numbers selected are not in the directory,"
        + sb.ToString()+
        " you wish to continue?') == true){Redirect();};", true);
         }
}
</script>
```

Hope it can help you.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem I am having is that the pop up does not show UNLESS i add
>   the return statement as follows

The `JavaScript code` will be executed once the [**Page Life Cycle**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is done executing it's all events. So, return does not have any significance here.

---

**Corrective Action**

Move the code (condition and `Redirect` to another page) to a JavaScript function. Call the Function in your `RegisterStartupScript`.

Answer (score 0):

this may be your soultion. this is a sample for restricting navigation based on user input from confirm box.

[Check here](http://vetrivelmpitdevotee.blogspot.com/2011/10/how-to-restrict-accidential-navigation.html)